# How to update all records in table with incremented values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "House":

```
id | name | order
1  | riw  | 0
2  | hnm  | 0
4  | vse  | 0
5  | tes  | 0
```

And I would like to simply receive:

```
id | name | order
1  | riw  | 0
2  | hnm  | 1
4  | vse  | 2
5  | tes  | 3
```

So I tried:

```
UPDATE house SET position = position + 1
```

but how can I increment this values?

Comment: how big is your table?

Comment: Can we assume that the records are already in order in the table and you just need to update the Order field?  Also, are you asking how to add a new record and if so, then will it be to the beginning of the list, the end or somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 10):

Use `id` column to update:

```
UPDATE house SET order = id - 1
```

If you feel `id` can start from n value other than 1, try:

```
SET @position:=0;
update house
set order=@position:=@position+1
```

Comment: Ok, for my example this is good answer, but I need it for others examples (without ID from 1).

Comment: For example I have in database positions with ID in order: 57, 59, 60, 65.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can use **ROWNUM**

In My SQL : **Rank** can be used. Also You can create temp table with identity column which is auto-incremented. Then insert into temp table from your main table. And finally truncate your main table and insert back from temp table.

Also you can look at below query which you can modify for your purpose.

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
FROM
    employees
LIMIT 5;
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Rank can be used"?  Is there a reference page I can go to in order to learn about Rank?

Answer (score 1):

This would do

```
update house as hs 
inner join 
 (select id, (@row:=@row+1) as o from house h, (select @row:=0) as r) as hsjoin 
 on hsjoin.id = hs.id
set hs.order = hsjoin.o;
```

Basically use a variable and increment it, join the table and update the order

Comment: This is the best answer, at least for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL, create a temporary table with the function Row_Number() and then update your table joining with the temporary table

At the moment I am not sure if the syntax is totally right but I have decided to answer more because of the approach I have thought of

Example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id asc) AS RowNr,
       id, name
INTO #tmp
FROM house

UPDATE  house
SET     h.position = t.RowNr - 1
FROM    house h
JOIN    tmp   t ON h.id = t.id
```